# Why usercontrols loaded event is not fired

Tags: wpf, events, event-handling, load, code-behind

I have a user control. I had this situations again some times but could always fix it by using the "`New()` contructor". But I still wonder what I am doing wrong because **the load event has to be fired if control was loaded**!

Here is some code:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:OUTPUT___VideoContent"
    Title="OUTPUT - VideoContent" Height="350" Width="525" Icon="/OUTPUT%20-%20VideoContent;component/Images/VideoContent.png">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid x:Name="VideoGrid">
            <my:ucVideoPresenter x:Name="VideoPresenter1"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtInfo" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and in the usercontrol, the load event is declared on WPF or codebehing without any success!
[image: Usercontrol wpf]

[image: Usercontrol codebehind]

Comment: Have you ever figured out what was the problem? I'm currently facing the same problem.

Comment: No I did not. I used my own booelan in LayoutUpdated event to check if the control is drawn first time. In that case I will initialize stuff like if I do in Load event.

Comment: That solution is not healthy. The reason for this is typically an exception that is thrown during initialization of components, and that effectively stops initialisation before controls are done loading.
Such exceptions will not be handled unless you put initialisations in a try/catch. And you'll not notice it in the debugger, except that a side effect is that all controllers that are initialized after the exceptions is never fully loaded. Hence the loaded event for them is never fired. You should check all initialization code for exceptions, for instance by stepping the code.

Answer (score 11):

This is because an exception is being thrown in the 'Loaded' eventhandler. The exception may be occurring as a result of a mixed mode assembly or some other exception that is "user handled", and the WPF framework is catching it (unknown to the debugger). This causes the debugger not to break when a breakpoint is set within the Loaded method.

To make sure you can see exactly what error is occurring:

1. In VS2010 go to Debug | Exceptions.
2. Tick "Thrown" exception radio boxes for the exceptions that may be applicable in your case.
3. Re-run the app and VS2010 should break on the exception that is being thrown in the event handler.
4. Debug according to a now known exception.

Comment: Do you know how to add event handler "not firing" exception? "Add" option does not give any ready bounded to events or there is no anything close to "System.Windows.Input".

Answer (score 3):

Does your UserControl constructor still make a call `InitializeComponent()`, without this, it will not build up its visuals and the `Loaded` event *may* not fire.

Comment: `InitializeComponent()`  is completed correctly. Usercontrol has no Exceptions while loading.