# Winforms UserControl Load event not fired

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

For some reason, the `Load` event is not fired. Having trouble similar to [Why usercontrols loaded event is not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621888/why-usercontrols-loaded-event-is-not-fired), so I tried to change the VS exception "handling" as suggested, but no exception is thrown.

As suggested in this topic [UserControl Load event not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220483/usercontrol-load-event-not-fired), if I override the OnLoad method, it is called. Is there any difference between the `Load` event and the `OnLoad` method? Any idea why one is called, but the other is not?

In the `UserControl` Inicialization

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MessageItemUC_Load);
```

And the methods

```
private void MessageItemUC_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    //is not called
}
protected override void OnLoad( EventArgs e ) {
    //is called
    base.OnLoad( e );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OnLoad is the method which is responsible for firing Load event. So if someone overwrites OnLoad method without calling Base.OnLoad then the Load event may not fire. Or if someone marked Load event as handled then it may not fire as well

Comment: Neither is happening, `OnLoad` was not overriden.

Comment: I did subsribe to the `Load` event if thats what's on your mind.

Comment: you subscribed to the load event...of what. Did you call the load event?

Comment: @pikausp try to fire the Load event when overwriting and see what happens

Comment: @CalvinSmith I subscribed to the `Load` event of the `UserControl`, just waiting for it to be fired. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Steve If i call it, it does run the method. But it's called before the constructor reaches the end, basically before it leaves the init method.

Comment: @pikausp well something is not loaded correctly then